# Unit testing Angular bootstrapping code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

**UPDATE: Worked out a solution I'm comfortable with, the answer is below.**

I have an app that uses manual bootstrapping, with a chunk of code that essentially looks like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
        angular.element( document ).ready( function () {

            function fetchLabels( sLang, labelPath ) {
                // retrieves json files, builds an object and injects a constant into an angular module
            }

            function rMerge( oDestination, oSource ) {
                // recursive deep merge function
            }

            function bootstrapApplication() {
                angular.element( document ).ready( function () {
                    angular.bootstrap( document, [ 'dms.webui' ] );
                });
            }

            fetchLabels( 'en_AU' ).then( bootstrapApplication );

        }
```

It works great - essentially fetches two json files, combines them and injects the result as a constant, then bootstraps the app.

My question is how to unit test these functions? I want to write something to test the fetchLabels() and rMerge() methods, but I'm not sure how to go about it. My first thought was separate the methods out into a service and use it that way, but I wasn't sure if I could actually invoke my own service this way before I've even bootstrapped the application?

Otherwise, can anyone suggest a way to separate out these methods into something standalone that I can test more readily?

Comment: do these functions do something so complicated that you need to test their implementations? Why not just test the *result* by asserting that your constant injectable has the correct values?

Comment: You're right, I can just test the result for the sake of ensuring the total concept works, but I'd like to attach tests to the methods so we can catch any regressions if a future developer makes changes to the methods themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after some fiddling, I found a solution I'm happy with.

I moved the methods into the Labels Service, and modified the labels module file to preset an empty object into the relevant constant.

I added an exception to my grunt injection setup to ignore the label service files, and instead manually called them earlier where I am calling the module file itself.

I took the direct injection code for $http and $q from the bootstrap script and put them inside the Label service, as they aren't available for normal injection prior to bootstrap.

Finally I manually loaded the labels module, injected the Labels service, then used the Labels service to execute the aforementioned methods.

So my bootstrap script now looks like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var injector = angular.injector( [ 'labels' ] );
    var Labels = injector.get( 'Labels' );

    /**
     * Executes the actual bootstrapping
     */
    function bootstrapApplication() {
        angular.element( document ).ready( function () {
            angular.bootstrap( document, [ 'myAppModule' ] );
        });
    }

    // get the label files and build the labels constant, then load the app
    Labels.fetchLabels( 'en_AU', '/lang/' ).then( bootstrapApplication );

})();
```

And I can properly unit test the Labels service discretely. The loading order and adding extra bits to the normal way of loading modules for us is an exception, but I'm comfortable that it's specific purpose warrants the exception, and it leaves us in a much more flexible position for testing.